# Strange result when comparing two Lists

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I want to compare two lists. I want to check if List2 has any of the items in List1. I get unexpected result. Please see my code below.

test code class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool loop = true;
        int textcount = 1;
        while (loop)
        {

            var collection1 = GetCollection();
            var collection2 = GetCollection();

            Console.WriteLine("Test No " + textcount.ToString());


            Console.WriteLine("Collection 1 =" + String.Join(", ", collection1.ToArray()));

            Console.WriteLine("Collection 2 =" + String.Join(", ", collection2.ToArray()));

            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            var hasitem = collection1.Any(item => collection2.Contains(item));

            watch.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(hasitem.ToString() + "  Found in " + watch.ElapsedTicks.ToString());
            watch.Reset();

            watch.Start();
            var hasAtLeastOne = collection1.Intersect(collection2).Any();
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(hasAtLeastOne.ToString() + "  With Intersect Found in " + watch.ElapsedTicks.ToString());
            textcount++;
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }
    static Random ran = new Random();
    private static IEnumerable<int> GetCollection()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            yield return ran.Next(i, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

and the result is very annoying. see the last 4 result.

```
Test No 1
Collection 1 =10, 8, 18, 6, 11
Collection 2 =3, 12, 18, 13, 6
True  Found in 3075
True  With Intersect Found in 15297
 Test No 2
Collection 1 =18, 13, 7, 18, 5
Collection 2 =12, 18, 8, 3, 5
True  Found in 22
True  With Intersect Found in 100
 Test No 3
Collection 1 =1, 6, 15, 7, 9
Collection 2 =16, 15, 14, 14, 12
True  Found in 21
True  With Intersect Found in 23
 Test No 4
Collection 1 =3, 16, 7, 4, 19
Collection 2 =6, 3, 15, 15, 9
True  Found in 21
True  With Intersect Found in 56
 Test No 5
Collection 1 =18, 18, 9, 17, 10
Collection 2 =17, 12, 4, 3, 11
True  Found in 25
True  With Intersect Found in 20
 Test No 6
Collection 1 =9, 9, 2, 17, 19
Collection 2 =17, 2, 18, 3, 15
False  Found in 109
False  With Intersect Found in 41
 Test No 7
Collection 1 =3, 15, 3, 5, 5
Collection 2 =2, 2, 11, 7, 6
True  Found in 22
False  With Intersect Found in 15
 Test No 8
Collection 1 =7, 14, 17, 14, 18
Collection 2 =18, 4, 7, 18, 16
False  Found in 28
True  With Intersect Found in 19
 Test No 9
Collection 1 =3, 9, 6, 18, 9
Collection 2 =10, 3, 17, 17, 18
True  Found in 28
True  With Intersect Found in 22
 Test No 10
Collection 1 =15, 18, 2, 9, 8
Collection 2 =10, 15, 3, 10, 19
False  Found in 135
True  With Intersect Found in 128
 Test No 11
Collection 1 =6, 2, 17, 18, 18
Collection 2 =14, 16, 14, 6, 4
False  Found in 20
False  With Intersect Found in 17
```

Comment: @jodha you aren't creating a list. you are just using `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that what you call "collection" is actually an unstable sequence of items that changes everytime it is enumerated. The reason for this is the way you implemented `GetCollection`. Using `yield return` basically returns a blue print on how to create the sequence. It doesn't return the sequence itself.
And so, everytime that "blue print" is being enumerated, it is being used to create a new sequence. 
You can verify this by simply outputing your "collections" twice. You will see that the values are different each time.

And that's the reason why your test yields completely arbitrary results:
You enumerate each collection three times:

1. First enumeration happens when you output it to the console
2. Second enumeration happens on the test with `Any` and `Contains`. Because this starts a new enumeration new random numbers will be generated.
3. Third enumeration happens on the `Intersect` test. This creates yet another set of random numbers.

To fix it, create a stable sequence by calling `ToArray()` on the result of `GetCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GetCollection()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        yield return ran.Next(i, 20);
    }
}
```

Make it into this:

```
private static List<int> GetCollection()
{
  return new List<int>
         {
           ran.Next(0, 20),
           ran.Next(1, 20),
           ran.Next(2, 20),
           ran.Next(3, 20),
           ran.Next(4, 20)
         };
}
```

And your problem will disappear.

The long explanation is that when you make an IEnumerable function, you can expect it to repeatedly call the iterator on various LINQ calls (after all, that's what an IEnumerable does, right?). Since you do a `yield return <some random number>` on each iterator call, you can expect unstable results. Best to either save a reference to the `.ToArray()` result, or just return a stable list.